# (JS) Refactoring Help - Farkle Scoring with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, refactoring

I've created an application with React for playing the dice game Farkle. I organized the combinations and their point values in a javascript object by manually typing out every combination (save a few I'm sure I missed). I'd like to refactor into something that's more efficient and fills in the gaps with combinations I've possibly missed. I'm new to coding and have no idea where to start or how I could go about it, so I figured I'd ask here for any suggestions.

The game is about rolling 6 dice and selecting dice based on their point value. Here's the scoring rules my app uses:

---

**SCORING**

1 - 10 points
5 - 5 points
Three 1's - 10 points
Three 2's - 20 points
Three 3's - 30 points
Three 4's - 40 points
Three 5's - 50 points
Three 6's - 60 points
1-2-3-4-5-6 - 300 points
3 Pairs 150 points (including 4-of-a-kind and a pair)

Note that scoring combinations only count when made with a single throw.
(Example: If a player rolls a 1 and sets it aside and then rolls two 1’s on their next throw, they only score 30 points, not 100.)

Sometimes a single roll will provide multiple ways to score.
For example, a player rolling 1-2-4-5-5-5 could score one of the following:

10 points for the 1
15 points for the 1 and a 5
50 points for the three 5's
60 points for the 1 and the three 5's

---

Here's what my js object looks like within my app:

```
#combinations.js
const combinations = {
      '1':10,
      '5':5,
      '1, 1':20,
      '5, 5':10,
    //triplets
      '1, 1, 1':10,
      '2, 2, 2':20,
      '3, 3, 3':30,
      '4, 4, 4':40,
      '5, 5, 5':50,
      '6, 6, 6':60,
    //triplets + one offs
      '1, 2, 2, 2':30,
      '1, 3, 3, 3':40,
      '1, 4, 4, 4':50,
//.. so on and so forth
}
export default combinations
```

Any nudges in the right direction for how to more efficiently manage these combinations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scoured GitHub for JS farkle apps and discovered this solution:

```
// check array for all score combinations
function combinations(array) {
    // this array stores unused dice
    var unused = [];
    
    // make a copy of array, to avoid changing it (theseKeepers and thisRoll are global variables)
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        unused.push(array[i]);
    }
    
    // store number of dice in array
    var l = unused.length;
    
    // stores score to return (in case of multiple combinations)
    var score = 0;
    
    // if there are 6..
    if (l == 6) {
        // check for six of a kind
        for (var x = 1; x <= 6; x++) {
            var contains = containsAll([x,x,x,x,x,x], unused);

            // retrieve result from structured array
            if (contains.result == true) {
                // return score and empty array
                return {score: 600,
                        extra: []
                };
            }           
        }
        
        // check for a straight
        var contains = containsAll([1,2,3,4,5,6], unused);

        // retrieve result from structured array
        if (contains.result == true) {
            // return score and empty array
            return {score: 150,
                    extra: []
            };
        }
        
        // check for 2 three of a kinds
        for (var x = 1; x <= 6; x++) {
            for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                var contains = containsAll([x,x,x,y,y,y], unused);
                
                // retrieve result from structured array
                if (contains.result == true) {
                    // return score and empty array
                    return {score: 200,
                            extra: []
                    };
                }
            }
        }
        
        // check for a full house
        for (var x = 1; x <= 6; x++) {
            for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                var contains = containsAll([x,x,y,y,y,y], unused);
                
                // retrieve result from structured array
                if (contains.result == true) {
                    // return score and empty array
                    return {score: 250,
                            extra: []
                    };
                }
            }
        }
        
        // check for three pairs
        for (var x = 1; x <= 6; x++) {
            for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                for (var z = 1; z <= 6; z++) {
                    var contains = containsAll([x,x,y,y,z,z], unused);
        
                    // retrieve result from structured array
                    if (contains.result == true) {
                        // return score and empty array
                        return {score: 150,
                                extra: []
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // if there are five or more..
    if (l >= 5) {
        // check for five of a kind
        for (var x = 1; x <= 6; x++) {
            var contains = containsAll([x,x,x,x,x], unused);
        
            // retrieve result from structured array
            if (contains.result == true) {
                score += 300;
            
                // retrieve unused array from structured array
                unused = contains.array;
    
                // reset length
                l = unused.length;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // if there are four or more..
    if (l >= 4) {
        // check for four of a kind
        for (var x = 1; x <= 6; x++) {
            var contains = containsAll([x,x,x,x], unused);
        
            // retrieve result from structured array
            if (contains.result == true) {
                score += 200;
            
                // retrieve unused array from structured array
                unused = contains.array;
    
                // reset length
                l = unused.length;
            }
        }
    }
    
    //  if there are three or more..
    if (l >= 3) {
        // check for three of a kind
        for (var x = 1; x <= 6; x++) {
            var contains = containsAll([x,x,x], unused);
        
            // retrieve result from structured array
            if (contains.result == true) {
                // if they are 2s, 3s, 4s, 5s, or 6s..
                if (x > 1) {
                    // multiply by 100
                    score += x * 10;
                } else { // otherwise..
                    // they are 1s
                    score += 100;
                }
            
                // retrieve unused array from structured array
                unused = contains.array;

                // reset length
                l = unused.length;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // if there are two or more..
    if (l >= 2) {
        // check for two ones
        var contains = containsAll([1,1], unused);
        
        // retrieve result from structured array
        if (contains.result == true) {
            score += 20;
            
            // retrieve unused array from structured array
            unused = contains.array;
    
            // reset length
            l = unused.length;
        }
    }
    
    // if there are still two or more..
    if (l >= 2) {
        // check for two fives
        var contains = containsAll([5,5], unused);
        
        // retrieve result from structured array
        if (contains.result == true) {
            score += 10;
            
            // retrieve unused array from structured array
            unused = contains.array;
    
            // reset length
            l = unused.length;
        }
    }
    
    // if there is one or more..
    if (l >= 1) {
        // check for a one
        var contains = containsAll([1], unused);
        
        // retrieve result from structured array
        if (contains.result == true) {
            score += 10;
            
            // retrieve unused array from structured array
            unused = contains.array;
    
            // reset length
            l = unused.length;
        }
    }
    
    // if there is still one or more..
    if (l >= 1) {
        // check for a five
        var contains = containsAll([5], unused);
        
        // retrieve result from structured array
        if (contains.result == true) {
            score += 5;
            
            // retrieve unused array from structured array
            unused = contains.array;
    
            // reset length
            l = unused.length;
        }
    }
    
    // return additive score and array with unused dice
    return {score: score,
            extra: unused
    };
}

// takes in score combination and unused array; determines whether combination exists in unused array
function containsAll(combination, unused) {
    // l is defined up front for speed
    var l = combination.length;
    
    // stores unused dice
    var un = [];
    
    // make a copy of unused array, to avoid changing it
    for (var i = 0; i < unused.length; i++) {
        un.push(unused[i]);
    }
    
    // this array stores used dice
    var used = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++)  {
        // store index of combination die in unused array
        var c = un.indexOf(combination[i]);
        
        // if unused doesn't contain this combination die..
        if (c == -1) {
            return false;
        } else { // otherwise..
            // add die to used array
            used.push(un[c]);
            
            // remove die from unused (since most combinations contain multiples)
            un.splice(c,1);
        }
    }
    
    // take out scored dice
    unused = difference(unused, used);
    
    // score combination exists in array; return true and unused array
    return {
        result: true,
        array: unused
    };
}
// takes in unused and used arrays; returns difference
function difference(unused, used) {
    // this array stores unused dice
    var un = [];
    
    // make a copy of unused array, to avoid changing it
    for (var i = 0; i < unused.length; i++) {
        un.push(unused[i]);
    }
    
    // this array stores used dice
    var u = [];
    
    // make a copy of used array, to avoid changing it
    for (var i = 0; i < used.length; i++) {
        u.push(used[i]);
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
        // store first index of used number in unused
        var j = un.indexOf(u[i]);
        
        // if used number is found (indexOf() returns -1 if no match is found)..
        if (j > -1) {
            // remove it from unused
            un.splice(j, 1);
        }
    }
    
    // return unused (which now only has values that aren't in used array)
    return un;
}
```

huge shout out to GitHub user @danielbmckay